# Blog, News, Slashdot effects & Video

Tags: web-hosting, vps, video

We want to set up a WordPress 3 with the multi-site option enabled in order to have several (2-3) sites for news, photos & video. The expected audience is around 10-15k visits/day.

One of the problems is that we *know* that we will have big, exclusive news which will generate *Slashdot effects* generating spikes reaching to 50-70k visits/day. These spikes will be rather rare: let's say one-two spikes / quarter. Each spike will last 1-2 days and after this will fade. But it is *critical* for us that during the spikes the site(s) will be online *AND* responsive.

Another problem is that (at least) one of the sites will stream *video*. It is our video but we think to put it on a CDN (more on this later). ~250 episodes, each episode will be between 35-47 minutes. This gives us approx. 150 MB x 250 = ~ 37 GB. We plan to post two episodes / week. No, we don't think that all our audience will look at these. Let's say that we'll have at most 2-3k streams in the first day of a new episode. Also, even if we consider that the video is good (isn't it? ;-) - we don't think that this will generate any slashdot/digg (etc.) spikes). We think to use Amazon CloudFront for this.(or another CDN? suggestions please...)

**Giving the above what hosting solution do you recommend?**

We look at the following values: speed, uptime, budged, tech support - yeah, I know, the Paradise is in Heaven not here, on Earth :-). FTR, most probably we need a VPS, that's why I put the question here.

TIA for any comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this question is right for this site; but I'll have a go at it.

First off, I would use a value-adding commercial-use streaming video service that includes a CDN. There are several -- [Wistia](http://wistia.com/), [Bits on the Run](http://www.bitsontherun.com/), [Brightcove](http://www.Brightcove.com), [Viddler](http://www.viddler.com/) and many others. Research which provider to use carefully; you want someone who can deliver fast video to your entire (global?) user base. Generally these services will:

- simplify your work greatly (by handling encoding, player embedding code etc for you).
- offer good statistics/reporting on playback.
- offer fast streaming video optimized CDN delivery of your content.

**Regarding video CDN:**

> We think to use Amazon CloudFront for this.

That could work. Be sure to understand the difference between putting a video file on HTTP, true [video streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems#Protocol_support), and [pseudostreaming](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html). If you choose to handle video streaming yourself (which can be a perfectly reasonable choice), then pick a CDN that supports what you need and [integrates well with your player](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video).

**For the site itself, caching is the key to surviving a Slashdotting** on Wordpress. WP 'static page' plugins such as [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) help a lot.

If that's not enough, to go really fast you want an in-RAM reverse HTTP proxy (a.k.a. HTTP accelerator) in front of your Wordpress application server. Unfortunately caching Wordpress pages isn't that easy, as Wordpress uses cookies a lot, and strictly speaking cookie'd pages may not be cache-able. Varnish Cache has some decent [docs describing Wordpress' cookies](http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishAndWordpress), and how to mitigate this if you're using Varnish as your reverse proxy.